# UIAlertController-action inside 'delete tableViewCell method'

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uialertcontroller, delete-row

I'm sorry if this looks like a duplicate, I saw similar questions in here, I just couldn't get their answers to work:

I have a tableView with a list of user-created realmObjects. My current delete-function looks like this (and works just fine):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(allDiaries[indexPath.row])
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
}
```

My problem is that I wan't there to be a 'Are you sure you wan't to delete?'- pop-up with two options in it; "Yes, delete!" & "No thanks."

I can easily create the UIAlertController and get it to display it, when I slide to delete a cell or press the delete-button - but the stupid thing is, that the cell is deleted the very second the delete-button is pressed and only after that, the (complete useless!) UIAlertController pops up - and no matter what you press, it just disappears and the cell is deleted.
My current attempt:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you wish to delete diary?", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "No thanks!", style: .cancel) 
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete!", style: .destructive)// <-- handler: 'deletefunction'
    alert.addAction(action)
    alert.addAction(action1)

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        present(alert, animated: true)

        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(allDiaries[indexPath.row])
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
}
```

So obviously, I wan't to move the 'delete-tableViewCell-method' inside the "Action1"(Delete-button in pop-alert!) and away from the delete-button itself. <-- This should ONLY show the pop-alert!

I'm guessing I should have this 'delete-tableViewCell-method' inside a handler - but I just can't move the method out of this tableView-method to create the handler, without xCode complaining. So how do I create the handler and insert it correctly?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

 if editingStyle == .delete {
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you wish to delete diary?", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "No thanks!", style: .cancel) 
let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete!", style: .destructive, handler: { _ in
         let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(allDiaries[indexPath.row])
    }
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    })
alert.addAction(action)
alert.addAction(action1)
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: I tried something like that myself. I get a couple of errors on that though. If I try to add a missing parenteses on your code above, here: handler: ( { ... Then I get this one error: 'Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?''

Comment: Or if I just delete the extra 'end-parentethes' that you have in the buttom. I still get that same error

Comment: You are the man! Thank you a lot! I tried the first thing you did a thousand times... Never knew about the '_ in'  part... :D Marked you answer as correct - works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the closures to return the value of is seleteable or not from one individual method. Check the code below .

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        self.showDeleteCellAlert { (boolValue) in
            if boolValue {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        }
    }
}

private func showDeleteCellAlert(sucess: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you wish to delete diary?", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "No thanks!", style: .cancel) { (_) in
        sucess(false)
    }
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete!", style: .cancel) { (_) in
        sucess(true)
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    alert.addAction(action1)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: you answer is not able to understand , can you elobrate